# Enumerator 'Update' class does not contain a definition, but only for the Unit Testing method and not when it use inside the DAL project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, enums, dao

I'm trying to run a unit test for a Update method in a DAO (EmployeeDAO.cs) inside my DAL layer/project. Inside the EmployeeDAO.cs class, my Update method

```
public UpdateStatus Update(Employee emp)
    {
        UpdateStatus status = UpdateStatus.Failed;
        HelpdeskRepository repo = new HelpdeskRepository(new DbContext());
        try
        {
            DbContext ctx = new DbContext();
            var builder = Builders<Employee>.Filter;
            var filter = Builders<Employee>.Filter.Eq("Id", emp.Id) & Builders<Employee>.Filter.Eq("Version", emp.Version);
            var update = Builders<Employee>.Update
                .Set("DepartmentId", emp.DepartmentId)
                .Set("Email", emp.Email)
                .Set("Firstname", emp.Firstname)
                .Set("Lastname", emp.Lastname)
                .Set("Phoneno", emp.Phoneno)
                .Set("Title", emp.Title)
                .Inc("Version", 1);

            var result = ctx.Employees.UpdateOne(filter, update);
            status = repo.Update(emp.Id.ToString(), filter, update);

            //ask how to get status to work in MatchedCount/Modified count so we don't need DbContext use
            if (result.MatchedCount == 0) //if zero version didn't match
            {
                status = UpdateStatus.Stale;
            }
            else if (result.ModifiedCount == 1)
            {
                status = UpdateStatus.Ok;
            }
            else
            {
                status = UpdateStatus.Failed;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DALUtils.ErrorRoutine(ex, "EmployeeDAO", "UpdateWithRepo");

        }
        return status;
    }
```

appears to work fine, with no bugs being detected by the compiler. However, when I try to do some unit testing on it in this method inside my EmployeeDAOTests.cs/UnitTestProject inside the same solution,

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestUpdateShouldReturnOK()
    {
        EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
        Employee emp = dao.GetById(eid);
        emp.Phoneno = "(555)555-9999";
        Assert.IsTrue(dao.Update(emp) == UpdateStatus.OK);
    }
```

it tells me that

> (CS0117)"'UpdateStatus' does not contain a definition for 'OK'"

, which can be seen here to quite obviously have a definition for OK that appears to be valid for use in my actual DAO:

```
public enum UpdateStatus
{


    Ok = 1,
    Failed = -1,
    Stale = -2
};
```

And on another note, when I trade the order in which I define Ok, Failed, and Stale around, it stops causing Unit Testing errors but begins to cause DAO errors!

Very confusing, anybody have any input?

Comment: your case is wrong of 'Ok'

Comment: @VisakhVA Well...that's embarrassing. Mind making this into an answer so I can credit you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a small case mistake :) UpdateStatus.OK should be UpdateStatus.Ok :)